# Which RAM type should I get for my laptop?

Tags: ram

My Laptop is Sony Vaio model no SVE1511AENB and my RAM is of 2gb and its type is "1Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-11-B2". I want to exand my RAM so which RAM should I buy for laptop?

Comment: Sorry @aksmind this community is for programming related questions rather than questions about hardware, see here for guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: So where should i post this type of questions to get the help. I am in great depression because my work is not getting completed. Please help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Definitely off topic but I feel compelled to answer anyway. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use [Super User](https://superuser.com/about) or a hardware forum in future.

The link below says your laptop supports upto 8GB DDR3 1333MHz(PC3-10600) 204-pin SODIMM RAM so get 2x 4GB sticks. As long as you search for "DDR3 1333Mhz 204" or "DDR3 PC3-10600 204" RAM, it's then primary based on price. Some sites even say it supports 1600Mhz (PC3-12800) and you have that in your system currently.

I put in "ddr3 pc3-10600 1333mhz 204-pin sodimm 4gb" into eBay and plenty came up.

http://tech.firstpost.com/product/laptops/vaio-sve1511aenb-specification-293362.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @liam. It was really very helpful. May the force be with you.

Comment: Some sites suggest PC3-12800 1600Mhz as well, but I wouldn't go higher as you'd be wasting your money. You currently have that.